# Can I use a python function in DataFrame.selectExpr

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I've got a `DataFrame` that I'm executing a `selectExpr` on

`selectExpr("src.ID", "dst.ID", "SQRT(POW((src.X - dst.X),2) + POW((src.Y - dst.Y),2)) as dist") \`

is there any way I could do the path on the `dist` column in a Python function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm comming from scala but there's obviously a similar way in python.
the `udf` function from the `sql.fucnctions` package allow developers to create there's own `UserDefinedFunction` and using them inside the spark `Dataframe` operation and `SQL` queries.
here's the code that can perform what you've asked for

```
val constumeFunction = udf((x: Double, y: Double, z: Double, t: Double) => pow(x - y, 2) + pow(z - t, 2))
```

then you can call this `UserDefinedFunction` inside the `select` method like this :

```
selectExpr($"src.ID", $"dst.ID",costumeFunction(src.X, dst.X, src.Y, dst.Y) as dist")
```

sorry for answering with Scala code but I'm sure that there's a very similar way in python

Comment: @EdwardAshak if it works pleas make the answer as correct. Best regards